# Ordering by two columns at the same time

Tags: mysql, sql, string, sql-order-by

I am creating a report for a call center. The extensions in the report can either be the source or the destination. I need the report to order by both src and dst simultaneously. So all calls that originated or terminated at the lowest number in the extension will list first, than the next number etc.. etc... The following query will give me all the calls in order for the src and then all the calls in order from the dst but I cannot figure out how to achieve my goal. Thanks for any help!

```
select src, dst, calldate, disposition from cdr where calldate > '2020-11-07' and calldate < '2020-11-12' 
and disposition = 'answered'
and ((src in ('2003', '2001', '2002', '2004', '2099', '2053', '2051')) 
or (dst in ('2003', '2001', '2002', '2004', '2099', '2053', '2051'))) order by src, dst;
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to want:

```
order by least(src, dst), src, dst
```

This orders rows by the smallest value between `src` and `dest`; ties are broken by taking the smallest `src`, then the smallest `dst`.

Comment: The src and dst columns are varchar. I am not sure if this is messing up your solution, but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @MarkC.: if you want these strings ordered as numbers, then you need to convert them. A simple way to do that is to add `0`, like so: `order by least(src + 0, dst + 0), src + 0, dst + 0` .